# Sufficient conditions for $\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{mn} = \lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{mn}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Recently I came across with some problems concerning the following fundamental problem in the advanced calculus:
$$\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{mn} = \lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{mn}$$

Is there any sufficient(or necessary and sufficient, if there is) conditions for this limit equality? I know from the Fubini's theorem that $\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_{mn}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}a_{mn}$ under some conditions for $a_{mn}$

Comment: In both the title and in the displayed formula of the question, the two sides of the equation are the same as it stands now. Likely in the second term of each the letters $m,n$ should be switched.